# Finding optimal set of parameters of a multi dimensional model using python

Tags: python, data-science, libraries

Let's say I have a model that predicts the outcome of a set of variables Y<sub>i</sub> given a set of model parameters x<sub>j</sub>. I now want to find the optimal parameters x<sub>j</sub> such that the model gives values of Y<sub>i</sub> close to an optimal (fixed) set of target parameters Y'<sub>i</sub>. For simplicity, let's assume three model parameters x<sub>j</sub> = (a, b, c). Then, the dataset would look something like this:

| Model Parameters (a,b,c) | Output Variables Y<sub>i</sub> |
| --- | --- |
| (0, 0, 1.4) | (3.2, 32. 12,...) |
| (0, 1, 14.2) | (-4.1, 342. 13.5,...) |
| ... | ... |

The model parameters a, b, c are scanned through a discrete grid (which can be freely chosen with some limitations). Is there an easy way to do this in python with some existing libraries? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers here:

**EVALUATION**: The question is: what are **`optimal parameters`**? You need to define some objective function (*which will measure how good your model is with given parameters against that objective you've defined*). To **`prevent overfitting`** (your model is too closely adapted to the data you have and when applied to new data it will perform poorly), usually objective functions include **`regularization`** (ie we don't fit our training data too closely in an attempt to make it better data we might encounter later). Here is a regression example with `scikit-learn` with various evaluation/regularization algorithms you can use:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

**COMPUTATION**: if your parameters are continuous (they most likely are), then you have an infinite number of possible values (eg even between 0 and 1 there are an infinite number of real values), thus testing all possible parameter values is impossible and you **`need some algorithm to find values which are somewhat optimum`** (you may never find the global optimum, but as long as you find parameters which provide a satisfactory performance of your model that's what matters). Practically this revolves around sampling the data, evaluating the model output as indication for what new values to try, and repeating until we think we've reached some optimum (or that we've spent enough time/resources that we should stop looking). [SGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) is a very common method used. All ML libraries support it, here is an example:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-sgd-iris-py

Some library I came about recently (which I haven't tested yet), which takes some function + parameter bounds + some objective (aka goal) function as input and tries to find the optimal set of parameters:
https://github.com/python-adaptive/adaptive

```
from adaptive import notebook_extension, Runner, Learner1D
notebook_extension()

def peak(x, a=0.01):
    return x + a**2 / (a**2 + x**2)

learner = Learner1D(peak, bounds=(-1, 1))
runner = Runner(learner, goal=lambda l: l.loss() < 0.01)
runner.live_info()
runner.live_plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Max,  many thanks for your comment. However, I believe that you suggestion makes two different assumptions which are not fulfilled in my case. First, I am not able to sample the model space 'on the fly'. Secondly, I don't know anything about the model function (which I believe peak is, right?). So how can I proceed in my specific case?

Comment: You wrote `"I now want to find the optimal parameters"`. So you need to define what `optimal` means otherwise you're just doing computation without an objective. Once you have that, you need to use an optimization method for that function (once again there are an infinite of possible parameter values, you simply can't try them all).

Comment: As mentioned in the description, with optimal I mean that the output variables Y reach some target values Y', i.e. |Y-Y'| should be minimized.

Comment: So if everything is predetermined (you have Y, you have a discrete set of parameters thus  you just compute a discrete set of Y'), why don't you write a little program to compute your Y', compare with Y and pick parameters which produce the closest values? (or is it that computation time/cost and # discrete parameters are still too high?)